# Does map move-insertion guarantee that elements are or are not moved from?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

The standard "map" containers in C++ allow you to insert an rvalue:

```
T x;

std::map<int, T> m;

// m[1];  // populate "1"

auto it = m.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::move(x)));
```

The question is what happens when the element already exists, i.e. `it->second == false`. Has the element `x` already been "moved-from"? For instance, if it is a unique pointer, will `x` have been reset to null?

Patently the answer in the above case is "yes", because the moving-from happens already at the point of creating the pair. But suppose now I want to update the existing value, but still retain the information of whether the value already existed or not (so I can't just say `m[1] = std::move(x);`). Is it possible to "not move from" the object in that case?

I discovered in GCC that the following works [Update: works in GCC 4.6, does *not* work in GCC 4.8]:

```
auto it = m.insert(std::pair<const int, T &&>(1, std::move(x)));
```

But is this guaranteed to not move?

Comment: you could always `find()` first... :)

Comment: @Nim: That's not efficient in general. If anything, `lower_bound` with hinted insertion; I'm aware of that.

Comment: Btw, it's possibly misleading calling the return value `it` when it's a pair. I guess the question amounts to, "is `insert` permitted to construct a `value_type` object from its arguments in the case where it doesn't do an insert?". To which I think the answer should be "no", because the template version is equivalent to "emplace", and it would be pretty poor for emplace to construct a value unless necessary -- the whole point of emplace is to avoid constructing a `value_type` parameter. But whether that's actually guaranteed is another matter, so I'm afraid that's as far as I get :-)

Comment: Try `m.emplace_back(1, std::move(x));`.

Comment: @Xeo: Been trying to find a compiler that supports that :-) Do you have any guarantees for that?

Comment: @Xeo: `emplace`, not `emplace_back`, for associative containers :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Oops, my mind wandered when I wrote that. Yeah, I mean `emplace` of course.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Though `std::move` does not actually perform any move, and neither does `std::make_pair`, `std::make_pair` forwards its arguments to the `std::pair` constructor, which initialises its two value members from those arguments.

As such, the move is performed at that point, before the `std::map` has a chance to do anything. So, yes, you end up with a "broken" move for no good reason.

You should be able to take advantage of `emplace` (in order to skip the pair construction). From Table 102:

> Effects: Inserts a `T` object `t` constructed with `std::forward<Args>(args)...` if and only if there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of `t`.

Clearly, the library is still "forwarding" at this point so it's pre-move, and in your case no emplace shall take place so the entire expression ought to be an effective no-op.

**However**, *libstdc++* from [GCC 4.8.0 appears to have a bug](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6721d6afd140c18) in this regard: [`emplace`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01557_source.html#l00540) invokes [`_M_emplace_unique` on the internal tree](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01568_source.html#l01617), which forwards the arguments to [`_M_create_node`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01568_source.html#l00401), which forwards the arguments to [`allocator_traits<_Node_allocator>::construct`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01032_source.html#l00391), which forwards the arguments to [`_S_construct`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01032_source.html#l00253), which forwards the arguments to `__a.construct` which, with the default allocator, is `std::allocator<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::construct`, which is the pair constructor you were trying to avoid... all before the collision check in `_M_emplace_unique`.

It could be claimed that the standard is ambiguous in this regard, but I'd call it a violation of intent. Then again, [clang v3.4 with *libc++* exhibits this behaviour too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3efde78ebbc7f873), as does Visual Studio 2012. So if my standard interpretation is correct, this fails on all three of the mainstream toolchains.

I guess they all decided that the "if and only if" applied to the insertion, rather than the insertion *and* the construction.

I have posted a question on [*std-discussion*](http://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-discussion?place=msg%2Fstd-discussion%2FYQ4BGAvxIhw%2FjTfn1RIm9IkJ) aiming to provoke an improvement to the passage from Table 102 to authoritatively answer this once and for all.

Comment: Honestly I think a _Note_ in the standard pointing this out would be wise here, but I think we can deduce the above for now.

Comment: Grand, thank you! I'm finding those "container requirement tables" one of the hardest parts to scan in the standard...

Comment: Hmm... can you actually make this work with, say, a unique pointer? How do you spell the insertion -- `m.emplace(1, std::move(ptr))`? I can't get that to work in GCC 4.8.2, i.e. the pointer still ends up null.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah, it does seem to :( (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6721d6afd140c18) Compiler bug?

Comment: It seems so, given the standard text?! Associative emplacement support has been really slow in the coming (and see my edit: there's a difference between GCC 4.6 and 4.8 in the pair-with-reference code, too), so it's totally possible that this is buggy.

Comment: Thanks for starting the discussion!

Comment: So, the problem is ultimately that there's no separate "emplace(key, valueargs...)"?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Heh, I guess. I still think it should be possible to examine the key without actually moving, by examining through the rvalue ref itself. But I don't know enough about pack expansion (or, frankly, rvalue refs themselves) to say whether that's a wet dream...