# Calling std::map::emplace() and avoiding unnecessary constructions

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::map` whose keys are `std::string` and values are my own defined type.

Let's suppose I have the following code:

```
std::map<std::string, MyType> mymap;
std::string str1("test");
MyType value(pars); //I want value to be moved

mymap.emplace(std::make_pair(str1, std::move(value))); //A
mymap.emplace(str, std::move(value)); //B
```

Assuming `std::map` stores pairs, I guess A would generate a further call to `std::pair` constructor (`make_pair`), followed by another call to `std::pair` move constructor (in-place construction with rvalue argument).

And I think B would just generate a call to `std::pair` constructor.

So can we say B is preferred over A in order to avoid unnecessary constructions?

Comment: Did you try piecewise construction of `std::pair`?

Comment: No, it would just complicate my question. But maybe someone wants to elaborate on this.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace shows piecewise construction

Comment: I'm not sure how piecewise construction could help here; I'd rather say that `forward_as_tuple` could be used instead of `make_pair` to prevent the move-construction of the pair.

Comment: BTW, is there a mistake on the code example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace ? Why would first call to `map::emplace()` use pair's copy constructor? Wouldn't it use move constructor?

Comment: @jbgs you're right, fixed.

Comment: Hmm it seems there's currently no converting constructor from a (single) `std::tuple` (2-tuple) to a `std::pair`; you had to use something like a `forward_as_pair` to avoid the move construction in `A` (or just use `B` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/:

> Inserts a new element in the map if its key is unique. This new element is constructed in place using args as the arguments for the construction of a value_type (which is an object of a pair type) ... The element is constructed in-place by calling allocator_traits::construct with args forwarded.

So in option A, you first construct a pair which `emplace` will forward to the constructor (as an rvalue) for `pair` which will then do a move construction.

Option B forwards `str` and the return of `std::move(value)` to the constructor for pair.

So yes, option A constructs 2 pairs while option B only constructs 1.

Comment: *"which will then do a copy construction"* a *move* construction. The forwarded pair is an rvalue.

Comment: **Warning:** [In some implementations, option B constructs the pair even if the key is _not_ unique, which is probably a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20328676/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe *"some implementations"* is an understatement. In you answer you write: *"all three of the mainstream toolchains"* (gcc, clang, msvc). By the way, are there any news on that issue?

Comment: @Ali: Well, I didn't want to say "all". And no not as far as I know :( Discussion on std-discussion was inconclusive.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If "all three of the mainstream toolchains" still holds then don't be afraid to say that out loud. It's a shame that the discussion was inconclusive. :(

Comment: @Ali: I've been meaning to get around to tying up the loose ends