# std::map emplace without copying value

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, emplace

The C++11 `std::map<K,V>` type has an `emplace` function, as do many other containers.

```
std::map<int,std::string> m;

std::string val {"hello"};

m.emplace(1, val);
```

This code works as advertised, emplacing the `std::pair<K,V>` directly, however it results in a copy of `key` and `val` taking place.

Is it possible to emplace the value type directly into the map as well? Can we do better than moving the arguments in the call to `emplace`?

---

Here's a more thorough example:

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(double d, string s) {}
   Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
   Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
}

map<int,Foo> m;
m.emplace(1, 2.3, string("hello")); // invalid
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I've read a bunch of documents and come to the conclusion that it's not possible. However I am not the most experienced C++ developer so wanted to run it past some of the gurus here, in the hope that I am wrong. Can you help?

Comment: okay, read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Comment: Do you mean an *extra* copy? `val` is an lvalue, so a copy will have to be made at some point.

Comment: @juanchopanza, imagine the value was some more complex type and that it was neither copyable nor moveable (and so of course cannot be introduced as an lvalue, nor moved/cast to an rvalue reference). I want to provide the value's constructor arguments directly to some kind of `emplace` function so that it is instantiated using perfect forwarding and (presumably) placement new within the map.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I've added a further example.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace  for an example :)

Comment: @Pixelchemist, naturally I had RTFM, but without knowing what `piecewise_construct` and `forward_as_tuple` do, it wasn't apparent that they addressed my issue. Reading the docs on `pair` that Praetorian linked to offered the missing piece (pun intended).

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `emplace` functionality of `map`, and all other unique-key containers, is actually slower than the regular insert. For some reason, the standard demands (I don't have a quote, but this is what Scott Meyers showed at a conference) that the new object is first allocated and moved before it is checked that the key doesn't exist yet. If it does already exist, the object is destroyed again. Bottomline: unless I am proved wrong, don't use emplace :-)

Comment: I found it again on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smqT9Io_bKo#t=46m00s

Comment: @JorenHeit, thanks for the link. In my case the key is guaranteed to be unique upon insert (emplace) so I'll keep the solution given.

Comment: [Important note!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830349/calling-stdmapemplace-and-avoiding-unnecessary-constructions#comment31241611_20830492)

Comment: As the constructor could throw, it needs a strong exception guarantee, but so does the regular insert so I cannot see how that would be any slower.

Comment: What makes this code invalid for g++5.4 (it tries to use the delete copyconstructor) but valid for versions above ?

Comment: But your second example is rather strange. It never had a chance to work regardless of the availability of copy or move constructors. The arguments of `emplace` are forwarded to the constructor of `std::pair`. And `std::pair` in this map does not have a constructor that would accept `(1, 2.3, string("hello"))`. So, the code is invalid in any case. Your call to `emplace` should've looked like `m.emplace(1, Foo{ 2.3, std::string("hello") });`. That would indeed correctly illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The arguments you pass to `map::emplace` get forwarded to the constructor of `map::value_type`, which is `pair<const Key, Value>`. So you can use the [piecewise construction constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) of `std::pair` to avoid intermediate copies and moves.

```
std::map<int, Foo> m;

m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(1),
          std::forward_as_tuple(2.3, "hello"));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c475c316b77f542b)

Comment: This is very ugly, but you take what you get :)

Comment: Just adding that in order to compile this you should add `#include <tuple>`

Answer (score 36):

In C++17 this can more easily be achieved with the [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) method.

```
map<int,Foo> m;
m.try_emplace(1, 2.3, "hello");
```

This addition to the standard library was covered in [paper N4279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4279.html) and should already be supported in [Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/01/22/vs-2015-update-2s-stl-is-c17-so-far-feature-complete/), [GCC 6.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z) and [LLVM 3.7](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) (the libc++ library).

Comment: Yes, `try_emplace()` is really the best solution. In particular, `emplace()` always constructs a Key-Value pair on the heap. So, if the Key is actually found in the table, `emplace()` will delete that just newly constructed Key-Value pair again. `try_emplace` on the contrary does everything in the expected order: Check, if they Key exists, and if yes, return an iterator to that Key-Value pair. If not, then it emplaces the new Key and Value into the container.

Comment: Well, simple `.emplace()` is the only option if *the key* has to be constructed in-place, and has no drawback if you *know* it is not yet present in the map.