# C++ map emplace

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
    int a_;
    int b_;
};

int main() 
{
    vector<Foo> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(1, 2);
}
```

The above code compiles since emplace_back constructs the Foo object in place.

```
int main() 
{
    map<int, Foo> m;
    m.emplace(1, 2, 3);
}
```

The above code does not compile. Why does `emplace` not construct `Foo` in place using args `2` and `3` ? If `Foo` constructor has 1 arg, the above style works.

I am using gcc 4.9.2 which is not the latest. Does anyone think the above code would compile in later compilers ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27960325/241631), probably a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

The `value_type` of your `map` is `std::pair<const int, Foo>`.  `pair` does not have a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) taking three `int` arguments.

You can do

```
m.emplace(1, Foo(2, 3));
```

Or if you really don't want to call a move constructor of `Foo`,

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::make_tuple(1),
          std::make_tuple(2, 3));
```