# Can I create an unordered_map of string and atomic<int> key-value pairs?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, unordered-map

I would like to create an `unordered_map` of `<string, atomic<int>>`. I would use this to increment (fetch_add), store or load the values of the atomic based on a string (the key). For example, say I have 10 atomic integer counters, but I want to only get the values of 4 or them. I would like a `unordered_map` that looked like this:

```
unordered_map<string, atomic<int>> myValues = {
    {"first", atomic<int>(0)},
    {"second", atomic<int>(0)}, ... the last key being "tenth"}
};
```

Then say I had a vector of strings like

```
vector<string> wanted = {"first", "third", "tenth"};
```

The I would like to do the following:

```
for (auto want: wanted) {
    cout <<  myValues[want].load() << endl;
```

This should print out the values for the keys in wanted.

Can I do this? If I try to create a map as above, I get the error message that the assignment operator for atomic is deleted? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `atomic` types are neither copyable nor movable

Comment: So that means my approach is DOA? Is there a different way to accomplish the same sort of thing?

Comment: Instead of trying to copy `atomic` values (no no!) you can define the init data separately and just loop through it and [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) it in your map.

Comment: @Alf, can you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, creating an `unordered_map<string, atomic<int>>` is possible, but you cannot initialize it using the `initializer_list` constructor because [`atomic<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) objects are neither moveable nor copyable.

Since the values in your map can be constructed using a single argument, you can use the [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) member function.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::atomic<int>> m;

for(auto const& key : {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"})
    m.emplace(key, 0);
```

If your key/value type constructor takes more than one argument, to avoid copies and moves, you must use [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)'s [piecewise construction constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27960637/241631) and the `emplace` member function.

```
for(auto const& key : {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"})
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple(key),
              std::forward_as_tuple(0));
```

If your compiler has C++17 support, and the key type can be constructed using a single argument, then you can also use the less verbose [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) member function

```
for(auto const& key : {"fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eight"})
    m.try_emplace(key, 0);
```

Comment: Why `try_emplace` ?  `m.emplace(key, 0);` is just fine (without C++17 support)

Comment: @LWimsey Well, wasn't that silly? Clearly a case of overthinking it. Fixed now.