# Is there any reason to use std::map::emplace() instead of try_emplace() in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++17, [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) got a new member-function template: [`try_emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace). This new addition, proposed in [n4279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4279.html), behaves similarly to [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), but has the following advantages:

- `try_emplace()` does not move from rvalue arguments if the insertion does not happen. This is useful when manipulating maps whose values are move-only types, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).
- `try_emplace()` treats the key and the arguments to the `mapped_type` separately, which makes it somewhat more intuitive than generic mutators that are expressed in terms of `value_type` (which is [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)).

Given the above advantages, would you ever use `emplace()` from C++11 instead of `try_emplace()` from C++17 when writing C++17-only code?

Comment: `emplace` might be a few cycles faster because it doesn't check whether insertions happen, but that's not really a good reason.

Comment: with the added advantage of try_emplace i would always prefers this over emplace

Comment: @HenriMenke: ``emplace()`` does check for duplicates, *after* construction of the ``value_type``. It is much less efficient if a duplicate is found, because it is required to perform an allocation (and deallocation in case of a duplicate).

Comment: It should also be noted `emplace` is supported by more containers with more general semantics (cf. requirements on different sorts of containers). So in generic code not necessarily depending on `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, `emplace` has more flexibility over `try_emplace`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`try_emplace` can indeed replace most uses of `emplace`, but if you have an unusual use case of a `map` with a non-copyable and immovable key type, `try_emplace` will not work because it copies or moves the key. In that case, you must use `emplace` with `std::pair`'s [piecewise construction constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27960637/241631) to avoid copies and moves.

Even if your key type is copyable and/or moveable, piecewise construction is the only way to avoid copy or move constructing the key, so there might be cases when you prefer that over `try_emplace`.

Comment: Are you saying that `emplace` with `piecewise_construct` is always better than `try_emplace`? What is the point of `try_emplace` at all then?

Comment: I don't think that is what Praetorian is saying.  See the question for reasons to use `try_emplace`.

Answer (score 23):

`try_emplace` also doesn't support heterogenous lookup - it can't, because it takes the key.

Suppose we have a `std::map<std::string, int, std::less<>> counts;` and a `std::string_view` `sv`. I want to do the equivalent of `++counts[std::string(sv)];`, but I don't want to create a temporary `std::string`, which is just wasteful, especially if the string is already present in the map. `try_emplace` can't help you there. Instead you'd do something like

```
if(auto lb = counts.lower_bound(sv); lb != counts.end() && lb->first == sv) {
    ++lb->second;
}
else {
    counts.emplace_hint(lb, sv, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would always prefer try_emplace over emplace.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  A Crucial difference is that try_emplace will not construct the object associated with the key,if the key already exists.This will boost the performance in  case objects of that type are expensive to create

For example the below code  (Example from https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Cpp17-STL-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter02/efficient_insert_or_reassign_to_map.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct billionaire {
    string name;
    double dollars;
    string country;
};

int main()
{
    list<billionaire> billionaires {
        {"Bill Gates", 86.0, "USA"},
        {"Warren Buffet", 75.6, "USA"},
        {"Jeff Bezos", 72.8, "USA"},
        {"Amancio Ortega", 71.3, "Spain"},
        {"Mark Zuckerberg", 56.0, "USA"},
        {"Carlos Slim", 54.5, "Mexico"},
        // ...
        {"Bernard Arnault", 41.5, "France"},
        // ...
        {"Liliane Bettencourt", 39.5, "France"},
        // ...
        {"Wang Jianlin", 31.3, "China"},
        {"Li Ka-shing", 31.2, "Hong Kong"}
        // ...
    };

    map<string, pair<const billionaire, size_t>> m;

    for (const auto &b : billionaires) {
        auto [iterator, success] = m.try_emplace(b.country, b, 1);

        if (!success) {
            iterator->second.second += 1;
        }
    }


    for (const auto & [key, value] : m) {
        const auto &[b, count] = value;

        cout << b.country << " : " << count << " billionaires. Richest is "
        << b.name << " with " << b.dollars << " B$\n";
    }
}
```

For the above code

```
m.try_emplace(b.country, b, 1);
```

if there unsuccessful insertion the pairs will not get constructed which adds to the performance

Comment: So what do you do when you have one of the examples from @Praetorian's and @ T.C.'s answers?