# C++: how to initialize vector in map with non-zero size

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a map of vectors:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<bool>> mymap
```

At times, I need to insert a new element:

```
auto& newvec = mymap[42];
// Add stuff to newvec
```

As far is I understand (and assuming that 42 is not yet in the map), this will give me `newvec` with length 0 (constructed as `std::vector<bool> {}`) which I can then extend.

Is there a way to initialize the vector to some size `n` right away?

(I am not concerned about performance, just wondering if there is a way to do this).

Comment: You can wrap the vector bool in your own class that initializes it at the size you want.

Comment: `auto & newvec = (mymap[42] = std::vector<bool>(desired_size));` will do it, albeit by introducing a temporary that may (notionally) be elided.    It is arguably more readable to either do `mymap[42].resize(desired_size)` before defining `newvec`, or simply do `newvec.resize(desired_size)` immediately after.

Comment: Doesn't [map::emplace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/) do what you want? You can use it as mymap.emplace(42, std::vector<bool>(125, false));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use `map::try_emplace()` (or `map::emplace()` before C++17)

[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has a constructor which takes an initial size and an initial uniform value. In your case, suppose you want 125 as the initial size. With a stand-alone vector, you would use:

```
size_t num_bools_we_want = 1234;
std::vector<bool> my_vec(num_bools_we_want, false);
```

Now, `std::map` has a method named [`map::try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) which forwards arguments to a constructor of the value type, which effectively allows you to choose the constructor it will use for a new element. Here's how to use it

```
mymap.try_emplace(42, num_bools_we_want, false);
```

to create a value of `std::vector<bool>(num_bools_we_want, false)` for the key `42`. No temporary vectors are created (regardless of compiler optimizations).

The only "problem" with this solution is that `try_emplace()` only exists since C++17. Since you asked about C++11 - that version of the standard introduced [`map::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), which does almost the same thing except for an issue with making a copy of the key. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46046828/1593077) for a discussion of the difference between `emplace()` and `try_emplace()`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Wrapping the `std::vector<bool>`

You could wrap the `std::vector<bool>` you want to initialise in the following way:

```
template<size_t N>
struct myvector {
   myvector(): data(N) {}
   std::vector<bool> data;
};
```

Then, declare `mymap` as a map whose value type is of this wrapper type, `myvector<N>`, instead of `std::vector<bool>`. For example, for `N` equal to `100`:

```
std::map<int, myvector<100>> mymap;
```

If the key `42` does not exist in the map yet, then:

```
auto& newvec = mymap[42];
```

will create an instance of type `myvector<100>`, which in turns, initialises an `std::vector<bool>` of size `100`.

You could access the created `std::vector<bool>` object either through `myvector`'s `data` data member or by performing `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<bool>&>(newvec)`.

---

#### Using `std::map::find()` and `std::map::emplace()`

Another approach would be to use `std::map::find()` instead of `std::map::operator[]()` to first find out whether a given key already exists in the map by comparing its returned iterator against the one returned by `std::map::end()`. If the given key does not exist, then construct the vector using `std::map::emplace()`.

In your example, the `newvec` could be initialized for this approach by means of the *ternary opererator*:

```
auto it = mymap.find(42); // search for an element with the key 42
bool is_key_in_map = it != mymap.end();
// if the element with the given key exists, then return it, otherwise
// construct it
auto& newvec = is_key_in_map? it->second: 
            mymap.emplace(42, std::vector<bool>(100, true)).first->second;
```

Actually, you can directly call `std::map::emplace()` without checking whether the given key already exists, but that will cost the useless creation of a temporary object (i.e., the `std::vector<bool>` object) if the key is already present in the map:

```
auto& newvec = mymap.emplace(42, std::vector<bool>(100, true)).first->second;
```

---

#### Since C++17: `std::map::try_emplace()`

You could use [`std::map::try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) instead of `std::map::emplace()`:

```
auto& newvec = mymap.try_emplace(42, 100, true).first->second;
```

This way, the temporary object, `std::vector<bool>(100, true)`, won't be constructed if the map already contains the given key (i.e., if it already contains the key `42`). This is, therefore, more efficient than using `std::map::emplace()`, since no temporary object will be constructed if not necessary. However, it does require C++17.

Comment: Wrapping the vector is overkill, I would really recommend not doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) member function:

```
mymap.emplace(42, std::vector<bool>(125, false));
```

to create a value of `std::vector<bool>(125, false)` for the key `42`.

As ネロク mentions, the above `emplace` call will construct the value `std::vector<bool>(125, false)` even if the key `42` already exists in the map (this is also documented in the cppreference page I linked above). If this is to be avoided, you can first check if the value already exists using [map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and insert the value only if the key doesn't exist. That is:

```
if (mymap.find(42) == mymap.end()) {
    mymap.emplace(42, std::vector<bool>(125, false));
}
```

Both [map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and [map::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) has logarithmic time complexity; hence, calling find before emplace should not hurt the performance too much in performance critical scenarios.

Comment: It is worth to mention that the temporary `std::vector<bool>(125, false)` will be created even if `mymap` already contains that key.