# Insert in std::map without default empty constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdmap

I have instances of `std::map<std::string,Foo>` where I insert and fill data. The class `Foo` is default-constructible, default-copyable. Then I do it by this (simple) way:

```
std::map<std::string,Foo> data;
for(std::string const& key : keys)
{
  assert(data.count(key) == 0); // it's assumed that the keys not already exist
  Foo& foo = data[key];
  foo.fill(blahblah);
}
```

After refactoring, the class `Foo` lost the default empty constructor. **What are the (simple) alternatives to insert and fill `data` ?** For the moment, I replaced by this but I don't know if it's the best/simplier way to refactor the code:

```
std::map<std::string,Foo> data;
for(std::string const& key : keys)
{
  assert(data.count(key) == 0); // it's assumed that the keys not already exist
  Foo& foo = data.emplace(key, Foo(requirement)).first->second;
  foo.fill(blahblah);
}
```

I also think it could be possible with `insert`, `insert_or_assign`, `emplace`, `emplace_hint`, `try_emplace`. I'm a little bit lost with all the possibilities...

I'm interested in solutions for C++11 or C++17.

Comment: Use `insert()` instead of `[]`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it looks quite similar if I well understand : `Foo& foo = data.insert(std::make_pair(key, Foo(requirement))).first->second;` or maybe `Foo& foo = data.insert({key, Foo(requirement)}).first->second;` ? Is there a difference between `emplace()` and `insert({})` ?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, which should be explained in your C++ textbook, which will also explain the important difference between `[]` and `insert()`. Do you have a textbook, or some other reference material that you can consult for all the details?

Comment: Unless you have a  good reason not to: Go for `try_emplace`, as it's the only of the signatures which will work with objects not permitting move/copy operations.

`emplace` and `insert` differ only between `insert` expecting an `std::make_pair` while `emplace` is that already doing for you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, of course, (re)-read textbooks is a good reason to remove stackoverflow from the web... My textbook is en.cppreference.com, and it's quite hudge. 
After reading in details, `insert` will create 2 copies if the provided template types are not exacly the same than the value_type. I prefer `emplace`.

Comment: You have the same textbook as me, then. And just earlier today I needed to look up something about ranges, and that's where I went to look it up instead of asking a question here, because this is not a textbook replacement. Knowing where to look up and how to read technical documentation is, pretty much, a mandatory skill for every C++ developer. And that's not Stackoverflow, which has a different purpose: asking things that are slightly less obvious then something that can be answered simply by looking it up in reference material.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree. But it's a subjective question. Reading the documentation shows that there is several acceptable solutions. My question requires some experience, this is not (yet?) in documentation, but experience is a foundament of stackoverflow. The existing disscussion threads about that question linked below is a proof that it's not a "read-the-book" decision.

Comment: @Ext3h You can do the same with `emplace`: https://godbolt.org/z/PhPdzWs5W. However, `try_emplace` is much easier to use for multi-arg constructors.

Comment: @Caduchon Does `data.emplace(key, requirement)` work for you? `data.emplace(key, Foo(requirement))` involves unnecessary move/copy constructor call.

Comment: @DanielLangr ho yeah ! This works for me. It's an easy way for me, because I don't have to specify the type `Foo` in the call (actually, I simplified: I have a lot of similar classes Foo-like, all requiring to pass `*this` at construction). Then I can replace by `data.emplace(key, *this)` each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply go with:

```
data.emplace(key, requirement)
```

or, since C++17, with

```
data.try_emplace(key, requirement)
```

Using `try_emplace` is generally better (see the question mentioned in the other answer); however, ASAIK, in your case, both options are effectively the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) together with `std::move` in order to add an element of a class that lacks a default constructor. This can be done after it was initialized with `fill(...)`.

Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int n) : m_n(n) {}
    int m_n;
};

int main() 
{
    std::map<std::string, Foo> m;

    // Create a Foo and insert it:
    Foo foo{ 111 };
    // foo.fill(blahblah);
    m.emplace("aaa", std::move(foo));

    // Verify it was inserted properly:
    Foo& foo2 = m.at("aaa");
    std::cout << foo2.m_n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
111
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Maqq9qE43)

Note that I used [`std::map::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) to verify that the element was inserted properly (using `operator[]` will fail to compile due to `Foo` lacking a default ctor).

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/)

> A call to this function is equivalent to:
>
> `(*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).`

So the literal replacement for the `operator[]` in this case would be using `insert` function. However, I would suggest using `emplace` in order to avoid additional construction of `std::pair`, which `insert` function accepts as argument.

Since C++17, you can use `try_emplace` except very subtle cases. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046828/is-there-any-reason-to-use-stdmapemplace-instead-of-try-emplace-in-c1z) discussion in order to see if preferring `emplace` over `try_emplace` applies to you case.