# C++ unordered_map emplace using a reference as a key

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, unordered-map

Can I use a const reference as a key when emplacing into an unordered map in C++? (It compiles and runs as expected but I want to know what is happening under the hood)

Will a copy of the const reference be created by emplace or I need to make sure that the memory referred to is valid till the map exists?

Where can I read more about this?

```
void func(
    const std::vector<std::string>& itemList) {
 int i = 0;
 std::unordered_map<std::string, int>itemMap;
 for (const auto& item : itemList){
  itemMap.emplace(item, i);
 }
}
```

Comment: It will copy the contents of the referenced string into the map key, see declation of `itemMap`.

Comment: Some link that might be useful - https://arne-mertz.de/2016/02/modern-c-features-in-place-construction/ , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830349/calling-stdmapemplace-and-avoiding-unnecessary-constructions#comment31241611_20830492

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

```
for (const auto& item : itemList){
```

has the same effect of following

```
for (const std::string& item : itemList){
```

And `emplace` just use the `const std::string&` to create another string at the place.

The reason why we prefer `emplace` than `insert` is that the first one will only create the object one time while that last one will create the pair then move it to the place.