# why does vector.emplace_back call the move-constructor?

Tags: c++, vector

```
struct Object {  
    Object() { cout << "constructor\n"; }
    Object(const Object &) { cout << "copy constructor\n"; }
    Object(Object &&) { cout << "move constructor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    vector<Object> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    v.emplace_back(Object{});
}
```

This gives me the following output:

> constructor
>   move constructor

Why? I thought that [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) does create the Object in place, so that no copy or move constructors have to be called.
From the description:

> The element is constructed in-place, i.e. no copy or move operations are performed.

**EDIT:** Ah, okay, it seems that I fundamentally misunderstood emplace_back(). You don't have to have the Object as an argument, since it is automatically created in place for you. You only have to give the arguments for the Object-constructor to emplace_back().

So, if I had a new constructor like this:

```
Object(int) { cout << "int constructor\n"; }
```

I would call emplace_back like this:

```
v.emplace_back(42);
```

instead of this:

```
v.emplace_back(Object(42));
```

Makes sense now, thanks a lot!

**EDIT2:** I wish I could accept all of your answers! :-P

Comment: Use `v.emplace_back()` to avoid any move.

Comment: **Only vaguely related warning:** With `emplace_back` on a map, you can still get pair construction, causing a move, even in cases when no insertion ends up being performed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20328676/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To my knowledge, that only happens with `std::map` - I've never seen that happen with a `std::vector`.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Yep it should be limited to those containers with `pair` value types. Hence my bold ;) I could have simply not posted the comment, but I was half-way through before I realised how pointless it was and... well... I don't like waste... :)

Comment: I stumbled upon the same question but for legibility reasons, i.e. we wanted to use `v.emplace_back(Object(42));` to be able to grep for the constructor uses. Now I thought I can solve the legibility problem without performance loss by calling `v.emplace_back<Object>(42);` but to my surprise this also called the move constructor. I didn't find the reason for that, any clue?

Comment: @RolandSarrazin My guess would be that `v.emplace_back<Object>(42)` is just another variant of `v.emplace_back(Object(42))`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`emplace_back` forwards its arguments to the constructor of the vector element class, called in-place on the next available position of the `vector`.

```
v.emplace_back(Object{});
```

is sort of equivalent to:

```
{
     Object tmp;
     v.emplace_back(std::move(tmp));
}
```

That's why you are getting a regular constructor call followed by a move constructor call.
If you want to append a new object with `emplace_back`, just call:

```
v.emplace_back();
```

Just for the sake of completeness, another reason why `emplace_back` might call a move constructor is: `emplace_back` may cause the `vector` to grow, and thus move its initial contents to their new memory location. This is not the problem here, because calling `reserve` guarantees enough capacity, but generally it's an answer to the question.

Comment: @Yakk Could you expand on that 'False'?

Comment: @Yakk: I actually tested this in my IDE, and at least on a practical level, my answer seems to work... Do you have a problem with my "sort of equivalent" formulation ?

Comment: That is strange.  The one I read had no `std::move` in it I swear...  I know SO sometimes collapses edits: did you add `std::move` after originally posting, or did I hallucinate?

Comment: @Yakk: Rejoice, for you are not crazy! For the first minute or so, my answer was actually missing the `std::move` call.

Answer (score 10):

`v.emplace_back(Object{});` will call a placement new `new (place) Object(Object{})` so a move constructor.

Use `v.emplace_back();` to avoid to call extra object constructor,
which will result in `new (place) Object;`

Comment: If you will try v.emplace_back() then gcc compiler will reports Default constructor Copy constructor

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What have you try ? It works as expected : https://ideone.com/FPzZfw

Comment: I tried the same ideone.com and for code v.emplace_back( Object() );
v.emplace_back(); I got  Default constructor
Move constructor
 Default constructor
Copy constructor

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What you see is due to internal `resize()` : https://ideone.com/8YQCd2, with some `noexecpt`, the last copy constructor becomes move constructor.

Comment: Oh, You are write, I totally forgot about this because in the original code there is a call of reserve but I omited it.:)

Answer (score 6):

`emplace_back` calls whatever constructor matches the arguments you pass it. In this case you have chosen to pass `Object{}`, which matches the `Object&&` move constructor.

When the description says, "no move or copy is performed", it means apart from the object construction that you specify. If that construction happens to be a move or copy then of course it is performed.

If you want `emplace_back` to use the no-args constructor then pass it no arguments: `v.emplace_back()`.

Answer (score 3):

The version you are linking is for passing constructor arguments. To achieve the desired effect, you could call `v.emplace_back();`

Comment: v.emplace_back<Object>(Object{}); still gives me the same output.

Comment: I meant with no arguments at all.

Comment: @gartenriese You do not need the `Object{}` in the function call.  Just call `emplace_back` with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `emplace_back` with an object of the same type that is stored in the vector so you are requesting a copy of that object (Same as `Object O(Object{});`). Since you provide a temporary, the move constructor is invoked instead of the copy constructor.